# What Are the Semantics of Javascripts If Statement

Tags: javascript

I always thought that an if statement essentially compared it's argument similar to `== true`.  However the following experiment in Firebug confirmed my worst fears—after writing Javascript for 15 years I still have no clue WTF is going on:

```
>>> " " == true
false
>>> if(" ") console.log("wtf")
wtf
```

My worldview is in shambles here.  I could run some experiments to learn more, but even then I would be losing sleep for fear of browser quirks.  Is this in a spec somewhere?  Is it consistent cross-browser?  Will I ever master javascript?

Comment: bizarre, I'm curious to see the answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers; if either operand is a string, the other one is converted to a string."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

So the first one does:

```
Number(" ")==Number(true)
```

While the second one is evaluated like this:

```
if(Boolean(" ")==true) console.log("wtf")
```

Comment: This is the most sensible explanation.  The if statement casts to Boolean.  Bonus points if anyone can find a spec for this behavior.

Comment: Well, the Mozilla docs have the following to say regarding the conversion taking place in the if statement: "Any value that is not undefined, null, 0, NaN, or the empty string (""), and any object, including a Boolean object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement."

Comment: And this concerning the conversion using Boolean(value): "If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false."

Comment: A JS Ninja friend of mine just IMed me this spec: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that it is the first part that is a problem, not the second.

It probably does some weird casting (most likely, `true` is cast to a string instead of `" "` being cast to a boolean value.

What does FireBug return for `Boolean(" ")` ?

Comment: Well, holy wars have been perpetuated merely by the definition of truthiness in programming languages, but in javascript I just assumed that since == does casting and === is an exact match, == true would be the natural definition of truthiness.

Comment: Boolean(" ") => true
Boolean("") => false

Comment: So, the answer is *probably* that the "==" operator does backwards casting (true => string "true") and then comparison fails. Kille me if I can find ANY reference that specifies just what the casting rules for "==" are though

Comment: Check out the next two answers :)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript can be quirky with things like this. Note that JavaScript has `==` but also `===`. I would have thought that

```
" " == true
```

would be `true`, but

```
" " === true
```

would be `false`. The `===` operator doesn't do conversions; it checks if the value and the type on both sides of the operator are the same. The `==` does convert 'truthy' values to true and 'falsy' values to false.

This might be the answer - from [JavaScript Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) (Mozilla documentation):

> **Equal (==)**
>
> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers; if either operand is a string, the other one is converted to a string

Highly recommended: [Douglas Crockford on JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/).

Comment: Good link, I had Javascript: The Good Parts, but I don't know where it ran off to.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer: aTruthyValue and true are not the same.**

The semantic of the if statement is easy:

```
if(aTruthyValue) {
  doThis
} else {
  doThat
}
```

Now it's just the definition of what a truthy value is. A truthy value is, unfortunately, not something that is simply "== true" or "=== true".

[ECMA-262 1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)
Setion 9.2 explains what values are truthy and which are not.

Comment: +1 for the most direct answer, as well as a link to the *actual* spec!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using === whenever possible, if only to avoid having existential crises.

Comment: This is pure silly. String.prototype.f = function () { return this }; "foo".f() === "foo" // what is the result? Identity is identity. It is a special case, not the normal case.