# using if(someBoolean) vs if(someBoolean==true) in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean

I was wondering if in a weakly typed language such as javascript, is there a significant difference between using

```
var someBool=true;
if (someBool==true){
    //Somecode
}
```

Or just using

```
if(someBool){
  //Somecode
}
```

Is there a difference in the speed of execution, or is there some semantic difference, or is one just preferred over the other?

Comment: Do you already know that the expression can only be true or false?

Comment: I am not sure in a boolean context, but always use === in JavaScript so you have proper coercion.

Comment: @ Eric. No I don't, that was just an example

Comment: @scrblnrd3 then as eric pointed out, you need to use === instead of if(someBool) so you have proper conditional

Comment: In my opinion, explicit comparison to boolean constants in *any* language (well, OK, any traditional C-like language, or anything similar) is an anti-pattern.  If the language has statement syntax that expects a boolean-valued expression, then comparisons to boolean constants are fishy at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantic differences are considerable, and they are as follows:

```
if (x)
```

has the semantics:

- Determine the value of `x`.
- If the value is undefined, null, zero, NaN, an empty string or false then the condition is considered to be false, otherwise it is considered to be true.

`if (x==true)`

has the semantics:

- Determine the value of `x`.
- If the value is true then the condition is true.
- If the value is false then the condition is false.
- Otherwise, pretend that the user actually wrote

`if (x==1)`

and start over.

I'm not going to go through all the logic for determining if an expression is equal to 1; you can read section 11.9.3 of Revision 3 of the ECMAScript specification if you want the details.

Comment: @OP: If you dislike `1 == true` evaluating to true, you can use `1 === true`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a little semantic difference. The `==` comparison does more if you have different types of values (e.g. [JavaScript truthiness in boolean to numbers comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6640637/1048572), [What Are the Semantics of Javascripts If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1615969/1048572)), while `if` only checks for [truthiness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10401297/1048572).

Yet, if `someBool` is always known to be a boolean value you should *not* compare against `true`, but always use the second variant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that `someBool` is in fact `true`, use the strict equality comparator (`===`):

```
var someBool = 1;

someBool == true;  // true
someBool === true; // false
```

This also works for other types:

```
0 == "0";  // true
0 === "0"; // false
```

As others have pointed out, there is a difference between testing for equality (using `==`) or testing for "truthyness" (using just `if()`). It's definitely worth knowing about this, but personally I try to avoid writing code that is not 100% clear in its meaning. Given the name of the variable (`someBool`), I would expect a boolean, so I would test for a boolean. If I wanted to know if it was greater than `0`, I would test for that instead (`someNumber >== 0`).

As for performance; the strict equality comparator is usually [a bit faster](http://jsperf.com/triple-equals-vs-double-equals/3) than using `==`, but the difference is negligible. Testing for truthyness might be a bit faster, but this is still a micro-optimization, which is rarely worth the trouble.

Comment: `someBool = true; (someBool == 2)` will return `false`, I think that's a big difference.

Comment: `==` checks for equality, not for truthiness. For example, `2 == true` is `false` while both are truthy.

Comment: @Teemu: Yes, but you would never use that in your code. It's just too fragile and too easily misunderstood by other programmers (or your future self).